# See error log for more details. (Packaing version to iOS)

Tags: actionscript-3, packaging, logfile

When I am trying to compile current version of my app using Flash Builder 4.5, I get error which says:

> Some classes used in the application could not be resolved for packaging. See error log for more details.

Where do you see this log and what can be this error indicates that the Flash Builder?

Comment: The Stackoverflow police is down-voting your question because you probably should have posted the exact error message as a quote and asked where on your file system to find the error log file. Also don't forget to mention your operating system.

Comment: The error message is exactly that, I can not find the LOG to see the details!

Comment: I'm sorry, I was actually not criticizing you. I was being sarcastic because your question got down-voted. I did understand your question right away and I think it's a valid one. Unfortunately quite a few people believe that "form" is more important than "content".

Comment: A Google search came up with this for example: http://support.elementriver.com/kb/sourcemate/finding-the-eclipse-or-flash-builder-log-file or this: http://srinichekuri.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/error-logs-in-flash-builder-or-flex-builder/

Comment: Thaks Nobu, i found the log and fix it!I finally compiled version!

Comment: my question are solved, but still -2 reputation, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LOG file is in the Flash Builder Workspace folder ".metadata" with the log name, he was able to solve my problem.